# Data in the table as the set of input parameters  to a stored proc in sql server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, import

I have procedure which takes the input parameters and populates in the 5 different tables in the new database. In the old database the data is put in one single table. The execution of the stored procedure is

```
exec registration ('abc company', 'abc', '1/12/2004', '1/14/2010', 
                   'active', 'www.abccompany.com')
```

The problem i have is ..

`'abc company','abc','1/12/2004','1/14/2010','active','www.abccompany.com'` the input parameters provided in the procedure is one record in a table in the database. I have 1000 records in that table. is there a way that, table data can become my input parameters to the stored procedure? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

As of SQL Server 2008 you can pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure. Doing so requires the definition of a user defined type to represent the input.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one row, you could 'teach' your stored procedure to take the needed data from that table and pass only the ID as a parameter.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateTables (@SourceID int)
AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Table1
    (CompanyName, CompanyNameShort, DateA, DateB, Status, CompanyWebsite)
  SELECT
    CompanyName, CompanyNameShort, DateA, DateB, Status, CompanyWebsite
  FROM SourceTable
  WHERE ID = @SourceID
  ... /* same for the other 4 tables */
END;
```